# html in tipsy tooltip jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, tooltip, tipsy

[tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) is plugin to facebook style tooltips using jquery. I want to be able to display HTML inside the tooltip. e.x : i have any image with `class='test'` when mouse over in image, i see tooltip with text(html) in `<div></div>`.

E.X :

```
<img class="test" src="test.jpg"> 
<div id="testtext"> bla bla bla ....</div>
```

Live Demo : Please mouse over in tags in stackoverflow answers. you see stats of tags.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From tipsy docs http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/:

```
$('#example-html').tipsy({html: true });
```